# Effect on div doesn't occur when the content is loaded from JSON file using Ajax.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have created an unordered list just like in this example - [DirectionAwareHoverEffect](http://tympanus.net/TipsTricks/DirectionAwareHoverEffect/) .

Because I may have a lot of content, I decided to automate the markup. I included the content in a JSON file. The file is loaded using the following code.

```
$.ajax({
    //cache: false,
    url: "../content/"+"benefits.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        var rows = data.rows;
        var item = '<ul id="da-thumbs" class="da-thumbs">';
        $.each(rows, function(idx, obj) {
            item += '<li><a class="hvr-float"><img src="' + obj.image + '" /><div><span>' + obj.title + '</span></div></a></li>';
        });

        item += '</ul>';

        $("#benefits-container").html(item);
        }
});
```

However after having done so, the JS effect no longer works and I don't see any errors when I use the debugging tool.

The JS effect for the DirectionAwareHoverEffect (according to the tutorial) is done using this code

```
$('#da-thumbs > li ').each( function() { 
    $(this).hoverdir({
         hoverDelay : 0
    }); 
} );
```

Of course, this code calls its own library given in the source code.

I included the content loading function in the $(window).load() function and the JS effect in the $(document).ready() function. But I do not get any effect.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: try console.log() and log each and every variable then you can get idea  where the program stuck!!!

Comment: If you are still stuck let me know

Comment: @kishan, your comment is not helpful at all...

Comment: @AmmarCSE Managed to solve the problem with your solution. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to use delegation like [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or you need to call the plugin after the ajax call and the appending of the elements.

So, either, after this line

```
$("#benefits-container").html(item);
```

do

```
$('#da-thumbs > li ').each( function() { 
    $(this).hoverdir({
         hoverDelay : 0
    }); 
} );
```

or try and see if you can delegate like

```
$(document).on('hoverdir', '#da-thumbs > li', function(){
         return {hoverDelay : 0}
    })); 
$('#da-thumbs > li ').each( function() { 

} );
```

Note, above delegate suggestion may not be %100 correct as I am not sure how to bind to custom events(and can't look it up right now, sorry :) ).

Comment: Thanks! I use the first suggestion that you provided. It works like it used to. Really appreciate it.